# Where do we draw the line between home brewing and micro brewing?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, users

I don't anticipate this being a big problem but I'm curious to know if a line needs to be drawn to keep micro brewing (large batch brewing) out of the site. I don't really see a lot of harm in allowing it but then again it may be a slippery slope.

Comment: I've just broached this point here http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/311/broaden-definition-to-include-pros-and-micros

Answer (score 15):

In much the same way that amateurs and professionals coexist on Stack Overflow and the other stack exchange sites, I don't see this being a problem at all. We all have much to learn from and teach to each other.

Comment: I agree. Most micro brewers start as home brewers anyways, so why kick them out when they "cross the line?"

Comment: I agree, especially considering they might have some of the best advice on the site.

Comment: Indeed.  And if we start getting a lot of question specific only to micro-brewing, we can easily just tag them as such.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be better if this forum was simply "**Brewing**".  I don't think there will be many messages from anyone other than **home** brewers, but I see no need to limit it.

Years ago, on the newsgroup rec.crafts.winemaking, I remember a few messages from a guy who had started a very small winery.  Those messages were interesting and it would have been a shame if something like that happened here and the pro brewer was booted out for not being a homebrewer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone should be excluded. Many pro brewers started out as homebrewers and got good enough to earn a living from it. We can certainly benefit from their knowledge to learn and improve our brewing efforts.